# How to use the ssrs sort2 method

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

Background:

- I use ReportExecutionServiceSoap interface to render SSRS reports through an ASP.NET application written in C#
- I have a working rendering service that already implements the toggle item and paging functionalities, so I feel pretty confident in the code.
- I am trying to provide the "interactive sort" functionality. Looking at the (very limited) documentation, the implementation should be very similar to the toggle functionality.

Here's my implementation of the Sort method in my renderer:

```
        using (var rsExec = new ReportExecutionService())
        {
            // Configure the service instance, specifiying the credentials and the sessionId
            rsExec.Url = BuildSsrsServiceInvocationUri(m_reportServerUrl);
            rsExec.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            rsExec.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            // Reload the execution context of the previous session
            rsExec.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
            rsExec.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID = sessionId;

            // Sort
            string reportItemResult;            // don't know what to do with this
            ExecutionInfo2 execInfoResult;      // don't know what to do with this

            rsExec.Sort2(sortItem, 
                SortDirectionEnum.Ascending,    // TODO: get this from method arg
                clearExistingSorts, 
                PageCountMode.Estimate, 
                out reportItemResult, 
                out execInfoResult);
        }
```

From my controller I call the above method like so. The sessionId is the ExecutionId of the previously rendered report, and id corresponds to the report item the user clicked on:

```
        // Sort the report
        m_ReportRenderer.Sort(sessionId, id, clear);
```

Finally I call my renderer's RenderReport method, expecting to obtain the output of the report sorted by the column the user has clicked on:

```
        // Render the report with the new sort order
        var renderResult = m_ReportRenderer.RenderReport(sessionId, ImageRoot, actionScript);
```

The questions:

1. Is my understanding of the API correct?
2. If not, what am I doing wrong?
3. If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, your understanding of the API is correct.
2. -
3. You did not say, what's going wrong, but I guess the call to RenderReport results in the same (unsorted) Report as before. Have you ever tried to call the Sort-Method again? I don't know why yet, but it needs a Render-Report and a second Sort-Call to work correct. All following calls to the Sort-Method working as expected on the first Call.